# Deleting home folders ~symbolic links in Mac OS X 

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, folder-redirection

I bought an SSD, so now I have SSD + traditional HDD on my Mac. On SSD OS + Applications. On HDD data.

I wanted to keep applications and library on the SSD and move my home folder from SSD to the traditional HDD.

I used this solution of creating symbolic link on the  HDD to follow my purpose. 
I opened the terminal and in my */Users/Homefolder* I've typed

```
 sudo rm -rf examplefolder 
 ln -s /Volumes/nameofHD/pathofexamplefolderontheHDD
```

So one after one I deleted all folders on my home folder on the SSD and created symbolic links on the HDD.

The problem for what I'm requesting Super User's help:

One folder, exactly the one named "Download" any time I reboot the system reappears. So now I have two "Download" folders and I'm not able to delete the one on the SSD (the original) anymore, precisely anytime I use

```
sudo rm -rf examplefolder
```

After rebooting it magically reappears. Sometimes using terminal it says to *unlink* the folder but after some time I'm able to delete it

For trying deleting the file I've also used this app/script called [Trashit](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/8214/trash-it), but that didn't work either.

Comment: It may be that the location of the Download folder is set by the OS. If this is the case, it would explain why the system recreates the folder on boot.

Comment: I'm feeling like the only option remained is to tear all down

Comment: Do you really need to remove the original?

Comment: The reason why i'm trying to solving the problem is that of all the folders the one where i'll have much more writing and reading will be the download folder. I can create another one and keep two of them but i've to manually specify the hd "download" folder for every applications that need to download files on my pc. I can go around the problem, for sure. Thanks anyway for your time

Comment: What if you symlink the original download folder to the new one? Then anything that tried to go to the one on the SSD would end up on the HDD.

Comment: Tried. Not working. Maybe i've to modify from the system preferences user the entire home folder from SSD to HDD. The problem is that this way i put also the library where applications have their log files on the HDD losing some speed. If i've some good news i'll report hoping this question will help someone in the future...

Comment: Alright, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Under System Preferences > Accounts > Right Click User Name in Side Bar > Advanced

It is possible to link the account with an alternative home folder.

Checking and editing these settings will likely solve your issues.